# wpalchemi metabox doesn't show value from my post type

Tags: metabox, wpalchemy

I record my problem here.

http://www.screenr.com/pg88

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

usually you need to

```
global $custom_metabox;
$custom_metabox->the_meta();
```

as described in the alchemy docs.  however i can't tell more unless you post your code.

Comment: I solved my problem other way but thx :)

Comment: i saw that, but i think it defeats the purpose of using alchemy if you are going to fallback to get_post_meta().  i use alchemy all the time and probably could have solved this for you w/ code posted.  in my opinion you will get better/more responses if you post code instead of a screencast

Comment: I usually use get_post_meta but had a problem... tried your way and it fixed my problem instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `$metabox->the_value('title')` inside your custom loop.

The WPAlchemy object usually tries to get meta information for specific posts, not a bunch at once.

Sorry about the `$metabox` variable above, I couldn't see what variable you're using.

Comment: So I moved $simple_mb->the_value('title') inside my custom loop and still nothing.

Comment: Try adding the `global $simple_mb;` inside the loop as well.

Comment: I did this too. But still nothing

Comment: Finaly I solved my problem with this piece of code 

`<?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $custom_metabox->get_the_id(), TRUE); echo $meta['title']?>`

but with this my problems don't end. I echo my values correctly but they showed only in last post. Here is screen http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/wpalchemiproblem.jpg/

Does someone know how to fix it?